# CMake & CTest : make test doesn't build tests

Tags: dependencies, cmake, ctest

I'm trying CTest in CMake in order to automatically run some of my tests using `make test` target. The problem is CMake does not "understand" that the test I'm willing to run has to be built since it is part of the project.

So I'm looking for a way to explicitly specify this dependency.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It is *arguably* a [bug in CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/8774) (previously tracked [here](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8774)) that this doesn't work out of the box. A workaround is to do the following:

```
add_test(TestName ExeName)
add_custom_target(check COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}
                  DEPENDS ExeName)
```

Then you can run `make check` and it will compile and run the test. If you have several tests, then you would have to use `DEPENDS exe1 exe2 exe3 ...` in the above line.

Comment: so I guess that the "make test" target will remain unused as it seems you have to choose a different target name ine the add_custom_target command?

Comment: Yep. The only difference between "make test" and "make check" is the former shows "Running tests..." first and doesn't check any build dependencies.

Comment: @rq - but how can I do this with multiple projects (when one CMakeLists.txt is sub-project of other) so each one would define `check` target and they may collide

Comment: @Artyom - in that case you're probably better of just using the equivalent "make all test". In fact, this is what I do anyway.

Comment: Actually, some consider it a feature (not a bug) of cmake that you can run "make test" and just *run* the tests as they are without doing any re-builds first...

Comment: I did this and now it *claims* to run tests but actually doesn't. It says 1 out of 1 tests are successful but it *does not run any tests*! When I deliberately fail a test it does not see it. When I manually execute `test/test_myapp` the CUnit tests run properly. WTH?

Comment: This doesn't work in IDE builds because "-C Debug" or similar needs to be passed to ctest. CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR Doesn't work because the test command isn't known at configure time.

Answer (score 60):

There is actually a way to use `make test`. You need to define the build of the test executable as one of the tests and then add dependencies between the tests. That is:

```
ADD_TEST(ctest_build_test_code
         "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target test_code)
ADD_TEST(ctest_run_test_code test_code)
SET_TESTS_PROPERTIES(ctest_run_test_code
                     PROPERTIES DEPENDS ctest_build_test_code)
```

Comment: This is the only one that scales up and doesn't force you to build the "make all" targets just in order to run the test.  A possible downside: details of build errors on the binaries only show up in the generated LastTest.log file and not on stdout/stderr

Comment: Good answer! You should add the config to the build target though. Otherwise it's not possible to run the tests in all configurations.

add_test(
NAME "${ARGV0}_BUILD" 
COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ${target} "--config" "$<CONFIG>"
)

Comment: This clogs up the test reporter with a bunch of phony tests.

Comment: If you are using CMake >= 3.7, the recommended approach is to use fixtures. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448477/618906) below.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using CMake >= 3.7, then the recommended approach is to use [fixtures](https://crascit.com/2016/10/18/test-fixtures-with-cmake-ctest/):

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
add_test(test_build
  "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
  --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
  --config "$<CONFIG>"
  --target test
)
set_tests_properties(test_build PROPERTIES FIXTURES_SETUP    test_fixture)
add_test(test test)
set_tests_properties(test       PROPERTIES FIXTURES_REQUIRED test_fixture)
```

This does the following:

- Adds a `test` executable target built from `test.cpp`
- Adds a `test_build` "test" that runs Cmake to build target `test`
- Marks the `test_build` test to be a setup task of fixture `test_fixture`
- Add a `test` test that just runs the `test` executable
- Marks the `test` test to need fixture `test_fixture`.

So, every time test `test` is to be run, it first runs test `test_build`, which builds the necessary executable.

Comment: If `$<CONFIG>` is not set the `--target` will become the argument for the `--config`.

Comment: I believe `$<CONFIG>` is always non-empty. It is a generator expression for the configuration name: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#id2 I'll edit the answer to wrap it in quotes anyway just because it makes no difference.

Comment: How do you run `cmake`? I do this way: `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make`.  And it looks like there is no any defaults and all related variables are empty, until `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set manually.  (currently on Debian 10, didn't check other platforms)

Comment: I am not completely sure: can you run several `make` processes over the same build directory concurrently? This situation may happen, because tests can be executed concurrently by `ctest`

Answer (score 16):

I use a variant of richq's answer. In the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, I add a custom target, `build_and_test`, for building and running all tests:

```
find_package(GTest)
if (GTEST_FOUND)
    enable_testing()
    add_custom_target(build_and_test ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -V)
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

In the various sub-project `CMakeLists.txt` files under `test/`, I add each test executable as a dependency of `build_and_test`:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/proj1)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(proj1_test proj1_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(proj1_test ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES} pthread)
add_test(proj1_test proj1_test)
add_dependencies(build_and_test proj1_test)
```

With this approach, I just need to `make build_and_test` instead of `make test` (or `make all test`), and it has the benefit of only building test code (and its dependencies). It's a shame I can't use the target name `test`. In my case, it's not so bad because I have a top-level script that does out-of-tree debug and release (and cross-compiled) builds by calling `cmake` and then `make`, and it translates `test` into `build_and_test`.

Obviously, the GTest stuff isn't required. I just happen to use/like Google Test, and wanted to share a complete example of using it with CMake/CTest. IMHO, this approach also has the benefit of allowing me to use `ctest -V`, which shows the Google Test output while the tests run:

```
1: Running main() from gtest_main.cc
1: [==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
1: [----------] Global test environment set-up.
1: [----------] 1 test from proj1
1: [ RUN      ] proj1.dummy
1: [       OK ] proj1.dummy (0 ms)
1: [----------] 1 test from proj1 (1 ms total)
1:
1: [----------] Global test environment tear-down
1: [==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
1: [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
1/2 Test #1: proj1_test .......................   Passed    0.03 sec
```

Comment: In this example, is there a way to get make test to do what ctest -V does instead of ctest? The ctest output looks very incomplete and just says that there is a single test.

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to emulate `make check`, you may find this wiki entry usefull :

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeEmulateMakeCheck

I have just checked that is does what it says with success (CMake 2.8.10).

Comment: This will build all executables when running `make check`. For tests with dominating compilation times, this makes `ctest -R` useless.

Answer (score 7):

Save yourself the headache:

```
make all test
```

Works out of the box for me and will build dependencies before running the test. Given how simple this is, it almost makes the native `make test` functionality convenient because it gives you the option of running the last compiling tests even if your code is broken.

Comment: Does not work with CDash. You have to call make all && ctest and then the building is not part of the uploaded testing. So build warnings or errors are not visible.

Comment: Also does not work well if you want a parallel build, since the two will run in parallel: you need `make -j4 all && make test`. And it's also flaky using a non-Make build tool.

Answer (score 3):

For CMake 3.10 or later, another option is to use the [`TEST_INCLUDE_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/TEST_INCLUDE_FILES.html) directory property to set up a script that triggers a build before a test is run. In your outermost `CMakeLists.txt` add the following code:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND
    PROPERTY TEST_INCLUDE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BuildTestTarget.cmake")
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BuildTestTarget.cmake"
   "execute_process(COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\""
   " --build \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\""
   " --config \"\$ENV{CMAKE_CONFIG_TYPE}\")")
```

The actual test configuration is passed through to the build via the environment variable `CMAKE_CONFIG_TYPE`. Optionally you can add a [`--target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) option to only build targets required by the test.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I hammered out and have been using:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_TESTS a b c)

enable_testing()
add_custom_target(all_tests)
foreach(test ${${PROJECT_NAME}_TESTS})
        add_executable(${test} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${test}.cc)
        add_test(NAME ${test} COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${test}>)
        add_dependencies(all_tests ${test})
endforeach(test)

build_command(CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST TARGET all_tests)
string(CONFIGURE \"@CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST@\" CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST_QUOTED ESCAPE_QUOTES)
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake" "set(CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST ${CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST_QUOTED})" "\n")
```

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Derrick's answer, simplified and commented:

```
# It is impossible to make target "test" depend on "all":
# https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/8774
# Set a magic variable in a magic file that tells ctest
# to invoke the generator once before running the tests:
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake"
    "set(CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM})\n"
)
```

It is not perfectly correct, as it does not solve the concurrency problem of running `ninja all test`, in case anyone does that. On the contrary, because now, you have two ninja processes.

(Ftr, I also shared this solution [here](https://gist.github.com/anordal/c73be8a8fc922bef6088105f9cbfe802).)

Answer (score -4):

All above answers are perfect. But actually CMake use CTest as its testing tools, so the standard method (I think it is) to do the mission is:

```
enable_testing ()
add_test (TestName TestCommand)
add_test (TestName2 AnotherTestCommand)
```

Then run **cmake** and **make** to build the targets. After that, you can either run **make test**, or just run

```
ctest
```

you will get the result. This is tested under CMake 2.8 .

Check details at: http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest#Simple_Testing

Comment: Downvoted because sometimes you only want to build the targets required for the tests actually being run.

Comment: This answer seems to misunderstand the question: The OP is already doing exactly as this answer recommends: Using CTest, `enable_testing()`, `add_test()`, etc. The problem is that he has to manually issue the build command prior to running tests. He wants the `make test` target to automatically build the test executables as necessary.

Answer (score -5):

All the answers are good, but they imply a breach of tradition to run a test by command `make test`. I've done this trick:

```
add_test(NAME <mytest>
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
COMMAND sh -c "make <mytarget>; $<TARGET_FILE:<mytarget>>")
```

This means that the test consists of building (optionally) and running of executable target.

Comment: :-D Rule #1: Don't use system without sh. Do you know such system?

Comment: Yes, Windows is one of these.

Comment: This is also hardcoded to `make` and loses CMake's feature of generating scripts for other build tools.