# How to add dependency in cmake targets

Tags: cmake

I have defined a custom target in cmake. I now want to ensure that this target is only build when the cmake target `test` was executed. How can I achieve this.

Lets say that I have a target `make coverage` which should depend on the target `make test` to be called before, or call `make test` before executing.

How can I define this behavior in cmake?

Here my code that did not work as expected. I want to achive that make coverage depend that make test has to be called before.

```
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        coverage COMMAND /bin/bash ${LIBPIPE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/scripts/coverage.sh
        DEPENDS test
    )
```

Comment: What is test? An custom_command or custom_target?

Comment: Strange. Custom target is always out of date, so if you run make coverage it should run test first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CMake FAQ](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_generate_an_executable.2C_then_use_the_executable_to_generate_a_file.3F) states that the `add_custom_command/add_custom_target` commands, which define custom targets, have a DEPENDS parameter.

**Edit**

This will not work for built-in target `test` because of following [feature request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/8438).

But you always can create custom target `check` or whatever as suggested in [CMake FAQ](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeEmulateMakeCheck)

Comment: I saw this but unfortunately it did not work for me. I have added some code i tried above.

Comment: Here the similar topic which could be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733475/cmake-ctest-make-test-doesnt-build-tests

Comment: Like @DLRdave wrote, you cannot set a target dependency for a test this way.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot add a "DEPENDS test" clause. The pre-defined/built-in targets in CMake (all, install, package, test, clean) are not available as actual targets in a CMakeLists.txt file. So you cannot express a dependency on a built-in target.

There is an outstanding feature request in the CMake bug tracker for this feature, but it is not yet implemented. See http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438

However, you could change your command for your custom target, though, such that it calls "make test" first, and then runs your coverage command.