# CMake: Project structure with unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, cmake, boost-test

I am trying to structure my project to include the production sources (in `src` subfolder) and tests (in `test` subfolder). I am using CMake to build this. As a minimal example I have the following files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) 
project (TEST) 

add_subdirectory (src) 
add_subdirectory (test)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable (demo main.cpp sqr.cpp)
```

src/sqr.h

```
#ifndef SQR_H
#define SQR_H
double sqr(double);    
#endif // SQR_H
```

src/sqr.cpp

```
#include "sqr.h"
double sqr(double x) { return x*x; }
```

src/main.cpp  - uses sqr, doesn't really matter

test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include_directories (${TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src) 

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK) 

add_executable (test test.cpp ${TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sqr.cpp) 

target_link_libraries(test
                      ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                      ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                      ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
                      )

enable_testing()
add_test(MyTest test)
```

test/test.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE SqrTests
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "sqr.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FailTest)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(5, sqr(2));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(PassTest)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(4, sqr(2));
}
```

A few questions:

1. Does this structure make sense? What are the best practises when structuring this code? (I am coming from C# and java, and there it is easier in a sense)
2. I don't like the fact that I have to list all the files from the `src` folder in the `test/CMakeLists.txt` file. If this was a library project, I would just link the library. Is there a way to avoid listing all the cpp files from the other project?
3. What are the lines `enable_testing()` and `add_test(MyTest test)` doing? I haven't seen any effect. How can I run the tests from CMake (or CTest)?
4. So far I just ran `cmake .` in the root folder, but this created a mess with temporary files everywhere. How can I get the compilation results in a reasonable structure?

Comment: I consider myself a CMake novice, so I don't know what the accepted best practices are, but FWIW I'd make a "sqr" library* that both main and test depended on. (* or the moral equivalent thereof)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

For questions 1 & 2, I would recommend making a library from your non-test files excluding main.cpp (in this case just src/sqr.cpp and src/sqr.h), and then you can avoid listing (and more importantly re-compiling) all the sources twice.

For question 3, these commands add a test called "MyTest" which invokes your executable "test" without any arguments.  However, since you've added these commands to test/CMakeLists.txt and not your top-level CMakeLists.txt, you can only invoke the test from within the "test" subdirectory of your build tree (try `cd test && ctest -N`).  If you want the test to be runnable from your top-level build directory, you'd need to call `add_test` from the top-level CMakeLists.txt.  This also means you have to use the more verbose form of [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) since your test exe isn't defined in the same CMakeLists.txt

In your case, since you're running cmake in the root folder, your build tree and your source tree are one and the same.  This is known as an in-source build and isn't ideal, which leads to question 4.

The preferred method for generating the build tree is to do an out-of-source build, i.e. create a directory somewhere outside of your source tree and execute cmake from there.  Even creating a "build" directory in the root of your project and executing `cmake ..` would provide a clean structure which won't interfere with your source tree.

One final point is to avoid calling executables "test" (case-sensitive).  For reasons why, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736838/424459).

To achieve these changes, I'd do the following:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (TEST)
add_subdirectory (src) 
add_subdirectory (test)
enable_testing ()
add_test (NAME MyTest COMMAND Test)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (Sqr sqr.cpp sqr.h)
add_executable (demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (demo Sqr)
```

test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
include_directories (${TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src
                     ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                     )
add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
add_executable (Test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Test
                       Sqr
                       ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                       ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                       ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
                       )
```

Comment: I just noticed that you also added the .h files to CMakeLists.txt files accordingly. Is it required? And what would happen if I leave them out?

Comment: @Grzenio This is just a convenience feature - they appear in IDE's like MSVC as part of the target, but otherwise this has no effect.

Comment: Where is TEST_SOURCE_DIR set?

Comment: It's automatically set by CMake when calling `project (TEST)` - see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html

Comment: >  they appear in IDE's like MSVC as part of the target
---
MSVC doesn't support to mark directory with headers as "include directory"?

Comment: How do you make the `Sqr` target (created in the `src` folder) visible to the `test` folder?
I'm trying to replicate this but the `Sqr` target shows as empty when the script runs in the `test` folder.

Comment: If I have many test cases within test folder, how to add them efficiently without calling many `add_test` manully ?

Comment: by linking your library to the executable, are the .h files known to the executable now or do you have to target_include_directories() to the executable?

Answer (score 67):

I like the example of @Fraser but would use the add_test command in the test/CMakeLists.txt and use enable_testing before add_subdirectory(test).

This way you can run your tests from the top-level build directory while specifying your tests in the test/CMakeLists.txt.

The result would look like this (I reused the example of @Fraser):

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (TEST)
add_subdirectory (src)

enable_testing ()
add_subdirectory (test)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library (Sqr sqr.cpp sqr.h)
add_executable (demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (demo Sqr)
```

test/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
include_directories (${TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src
                     ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                     )
add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
add_executable (Test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Test
                       Sqr
                       ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                       ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
                       ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
                       )
add_test (NAME MyTest COMMAND Test)
```

Comment: Thanks, I showed no tests via `ctest -N` until your the tip about enabling testing before adding the subdir.

Comment: @alaferg: they would otherwise end up in the test subdir inside the build dir.

Comment: I wish CMake had something that resembled structure.

Comment: @ruipacheco It's up to you to split the CMakeLists by responsibilities into different subfolders. Each of them should remain short.

Comment: add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK) doesn't work for me; it never adds any defines in my project.. using vscode + cmake extensions.