# Unable to build test unit with include(ctest)?

Tags: c++, cmake

My project structure is https://github.com/yumyai/cmake-sample. It is similar to project in this thread [CMake: Project structure with unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446495/cmake-project-structure-with-unit-tests).

Whenever I add `include(CTest)` into a top-level CMakeLists.txt, I couldn't build a test file (`make test` does not build anything). But if I comment `include(CTest)` out, I could build unit test exec using `make test` just fine.

Is this normal behaviour or I forgot something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample looks fine - it should work with or without the `include(CTest)` line.

It may be that nothing is recompiled after changing the CMakeLists.txt, so it appears that `make test` is doing nothing?

If you omit the `include(CTest)` line and do `make test`, then `ctest -N` should output something like:

```
 Test project <path to build>

 Total Tests: 0
```

If you add `include(CTest)` line and do `make test`, then `ctest -N` should output something like:

```
 Test project <path to build>
 Test #1: SqrTest

 Total Tests: 1
```

This should be the only difference - that the test is registered with CTest or not.  In each case, if `make test` has previously been run successfully, then the only effect `make test` will really have is to rerun CMake.  If the changes in the CMakeLists.txt between runs don't affect the actual test target, it won't be rebuilt.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. (`ctest -N` shows number of the test just right but `make test` still fail as describe in topic). Did you try that on top-level directory ? I build in ./build directory instead of at top-level of project.

Oh, and "nothing is built" as a no executable was built at all. I clear everything in each iteration to make sure that nothing amiss.

Comment: Ah - I never spotted this since it's not an issue on Windows with MSVC, but you shouldn't call your target "test".  Try changing the name to e.g. "Test" or "my_test".  (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/736838/424459).  I'll update my other answer to reflect this.  Also, you need to remove the extra `Sqr` from the `add_executable(demo main.cpp Sqr)` in src/CMakeLists.txt