# How to use test framework in my situation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, cmake

We have a solution with projects that is generate by cmake.

There is `src` folder that has all the source code. `Proj_Service1`, `Proj_Service2` and `Proj_Service3` reference same `Main.cpp` and `Base_Service.cpp` files. In addition, each project has reference to its own `ServiceX.cpp` file. All projects are console projects (exe). See solution structure below:

```
-Solution
----Proj_Service1
-------Main.cpp
-------Base_Service.cpp
-------Service1.cpp
----Proj_Service2
-------Main.cpp
-------Base_Service.cpp
-------Service2.cpp
----Proj_Service3
-------Main.cpp
-------Base_Service.cpp
-------Service3.cpp
```

The reason the structure above in that way is becuase it was decided in the company that each project should include only files that relevant to the project.

I want to add `Test_Proj` project that will test one of the services or/and all of them using googletest.

When I try to instantiate `ServiceX.cpp` in `Test_Proj`, I obviously get linker errors since `Proj_ServiceX` is not `lib` and therefore I cannot link to it.

What I thought to do is to create an additional project of type "lib", move `Service1.cpp`, `Service2.cpp` and `Service3.cpp` files to it and make all projects reference it. Basically:

```
-Solution
----Service_Proj
-------Base_Service.cpp
-------Service1.cpp
-------Service2.cpp
-------Service3.cpp
----Proj_Service1
-------[Reference to Service_Proj]
----Proj_Service2
-------[Reference to Service_Proj]
----Proj_Service3
-------[Reference to Service_Proj]
----Test_Proj
-------[Reference to Service_Proj]
```

Questions:

1. Is the solution I suggested above is the only way?
2. If there is a different, better approach, even the one that requires using other tools, I'll  be glad to hear.

Comment: quite common practice is to have two folders in each projects `src` and `tst`

Comment: @IlyaBursov, `Proj_ServiceX` is already a console project. The test is also a console project. How do I add a test_main.cpp to `Proj_ServiceX` project? Can you explain please?

Comment: you will have test cpp inside of each project, not as separate test one

Comment: But, each of the projects has already `main.cpp` file that has `main(...)` function . How can I add test cpp which also has `main(...)` function? I cannot have 2 `main(...)` functions in same project.

Comment: usually you don't test main, but classes

Comment: But I need to run the test and it's done from `main(...)` by using `int main(...) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}`. So, are you suggesting to add those lines to the `main` function of my project?

Comment: @IlyaBursov, can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: Making the services a library would allow you to link them to different mains.

Comment: @MichaelSurette, that's exactly what I suggested in my post. But, IlyaBursov says that it's common practice to put tests within a project instead. Do you have any input on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446495/cmake-project-structure-with-unit-tests

Comment: @IlyaBursov, in the link you provided they recommend exactly what I suggested to do - to move files to a separate lib project and then reference it to the test project. Otherwise, I'll have to add source files to the test project to compile.

Comment: @theateist with the only difference - project in terms of cmake, not visual studio project, so you will have single project with two "sub-projects"/folders

Comment: But, every time I want to generate a build for visual studio I'll have to add the files from "src" folder instead of just referecing one lib.
I suppose if you use cmake from the beginning it's not a big deal since you already have the list of all cpp files that you want to add in your cmakelist.txt, right? If you don't use cmake and/or don't want to maintain it it makes more sense to create a lib and that's all. Agree?