# Unable to open source file "doctest/doctest.h" and "cxxopts.hpp"

Tags: c++, c++17, clion, doctest, cmakelists-options

I created a repository from the template provided on

```
https://github.com/TheLartians/ModernCppStarter
```

I clone the repo and opened it using CLION and visual studio code. I expected that both the `doctest.hpp` and `cxxopts.hpp` will be added automatically (since both packages are available in the `CMakeLists.txt`. But this is not the case as I get the following errors:

```
cannot open source file "doctest/doctest.h"     
cannot open source file "cxxopts/cxxopts.h"
```

Comment: "Setting up a new C++ project usually requires a significant amount of preparation and boilerplate code" - well, that's just that author's opinion. I have never experienced any kind of "significant boilerplate" to quickly start a new c++ project. If some sources are missing in this github repo, ask the authors about them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But what will be the ultimate template for a standard c++ project? I was hoping the authors might be here to help answer the question :)

Comment: Well, no such thing as ultimate template for that, and that repo is quite advanced. It covers: sources dir, headers dir, tests, test coverages, docs generators, additional cmake modules, CI pipelines, formatting. Certainly you don't always need ALL of it :). Start with `CMakeLists.txt`, some `src` and `include` directories, and then add more things whenever you feel you need them. You can look for "cmake project" topics like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447765/4165552) .They are usually quite minimal.

Comment: I will check it out. I actually did check a few out before using this one from theLartians. It is because of some of these folders I feel it is suited to my use case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.