# Build VS 2015 solution with [CMake / Command Line]

Tags: msbuild, cmake, visual-studio-2015, appveyor

So far this is my command line to start a Cmake build:

```
cmake .. --build .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=release
```

This is good and works, and it generates a

```
Project.sln
```

and

```
tests/ProjectTests.sln
```

solution files.

I could open solution files with visual studio and build them and run tests from Visual Studio, however **I'm running the script from a Continuos Integration server** and hence I need to also start the build and run the tests from command line: how can I do that?

---

**I need to**

1. Build the library  (Project.sln)
2. Build the test executable (tests/ProjectTests.sln)
3. Run the tests (calling `CTest` from the same folder in wich `Tests.exe` is located)

Until now I tried to build using the command

```
msbuild Infectorpp2.sln
```

But that is failing ([error log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Darelbi/infectorpp2) just to long to post), if that can helps here's the [script](https://github.com/Darelbi/Infectorpp2/blob/master/appveyor.yml) on github. The main problem is that I'm not able to finally generate the `Tests.exe` file, once that is done calling CTest on it is trivial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/build_command.html), the general syntax for *building* a target (i.e. after *generating* the `.sln` files with `cmake -G`) using CMake is:

```
cmake --build . [--config <config>] [--target <target>] [-- -i]
```

It will invoke the appropriate compiler/toolchain commands for you.

See [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html) for the full list of arguments accepted by the `cmake` command.

Comment: When I add something as "config" or "target" options, cmake insist at saying that he don't find the source directory inside "build/ALL_BUILD" folder or inside the "build/Release" folder. I think just the --build command is bugged. I already tried that part of the documentation without success

Comment: I've noticed that you've used `..` (i.e. parent directory), but I think it should be  `cmake --build .` (i.e. current directory, i.e. where the _generated_ cmake files are).

Comment: thanks, now I'm able to build the library, but still the tests executable is not generated :/

Comment: Is this related to the issue raised by [CMake & CTest : make test doesn't build tests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/733475/865719) ?

Comment: I do `--build . --target ALL_BUILD` wich should be equivalent to `make all` wich also build test files, anyway I'll try now to workaround that, in case it works it's definitely a Cmake bug. Thanks

Comment: Definitely a Cmake bug, I have to refactor the project to use `philsquared/Catch` framework. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To complete the information for random browsers, the problem was finally wrong signature of functions.

CMake test driver requires signature like these:

```
int filename(int, char*[])
```

GCC/Clang accept this signature

```
int filename(int, char**)
```

while Visual studio require

```
int filename(int char**const) //still works with GCC/Clang luckily
```