# Are test sources handled differently by CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am building an application with CMake, which produces libraries and executables, in text mode and GUI mode (Qt5), and out course unit testing.
I have the experience, that if I modify any but the test sources, and want to run, CMake builds first new executable(s). If I modify any of the test sources,
CMakes runs the old executable immediately, so I need to compile explicitly the new tester before running it. The tests are in a separate subdirectory, the structure is similar to that of the other components, the sources are defined by a

```
set(MY_SRCS list of individual sources)
```

Any idea, what could cause that difference? (although it is a nuance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make test` target generated by CTest only executes the tests you added using `add_test()`, it does not build them. As it does not build them, it also does not check for changes in source files.

You can solve this issue by adding a custom target (e.g. `make check`) that first builds your tests and then executes them: [CMake & CTest : make test doesn't build tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733475/cmake-ctest-make-test-doesnt-build-tests).

Not sure if this answers the question, since you do not specify how you create and execute your unit tests.

Comment: I think you answered what I was looking for. I just use  RUN_ALL_TESTS();