# How to add a dependency to the test target in CMake?

Tags: cmake, pytest

I have some test added by command `add_test`:

```
find_program(PYTEST "pytest")
add_test(NAME test_something COMMAND ${PYTEST})
```

But before this test I need to copy some test files (including python test scripts to be run). For this purpose there is a custom target `generate_init_queries`. Since `add_test` doesn't create a target I can't use `add_dependencies` to link my custom target `generate_init_queries` and this test. I supposed that there should exist a `test` target in CMake and added the command:

```
add_dependencies(test generate_init_queries)
```

But it resulted in error `annot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "test"`. How can I copy files before running the test in `make test`?

Answer (score 4):

This question is highly related to [CMake & CTest : make test doesn't build tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/733475/1468532) which has gotten a lot more attention. The best answer nowadays (the question is from 2009) is IMO [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448477/1468532). I.e. using the **fixtures feature** in cmake available from version 3.7 onwards.

See the [FIXTURES_REQUIRED docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_REQUIRED.html) for a good overview and usage example. I can also recommend the [test-properties documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#test-properties) for a broader overview on what properties can be used to influence ctest test execution.

So modified for your use case, a possible solution would roughly look like this:

```
add_test(gen_init_queries
  "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
  --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
  --config "$<CONFIG>"
  --target generate_init_queries
)
set_tests_properties(gen_init_queries PROPERTIES FIXTURES_SETUP f_init_queries)
set_tests_properties(test PROPERTIES  FIXTURES_REQUIRED f_init_queries)
```

Answer (score -2):

Did it through `add_custom_target` with `ALL` keyword:

```
find_program(PYTEST "pytest")
add_test(test_something ${PYTEST} test_something.py)
add_custom_target(test_something_py_copy ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_something.py ${TEST_DATA_DIR}/test_something.py DEPENDS generate_init_queries)
```

Comment: You still need to run `make` before `make test`. Not sure what is your achievement with *ALL*. It looks like you had some **other problem** then one you describing in the question post.