# Running multiple build system processes concurrently

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, ninja

Imagine I have a build directory produced by `CMake` with `gmake` (or `ninja`) as a generator.

Is the following bash snippet a valid usage of `make` (and the same question for `ninja`)?

```
# make&
# make
```

I am asking because the following solution may lead to this kind of situation, e.g., by running `ctest -j 12`:
[CMake & CTest : make test doesn't build tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733475/cmake-ctest-make-test-doesnt-build-tests/56448477#56448477)

Comment: Building as root is always a bad idea.  Running two instances of make or ninja on the same directory at the same time will pretty much always lead to disaster and corrupted builds... probably requiring a full clean and rebuild to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

> Running multiple build system processes concurrently

There is no synchronization mechanisms. They will just run twice without any synchronization.

From experience in most cases, running `make` (or `Ninja`) at the same time twice, will run each build step twice overwriting each other in random order, whichever will finish first.